# mensaje de alerta pagina principal

Tags: php, javascript, html, script

quisiera saber como puedo poner un mensaje de alerta en mi pagina principal. La idea es que cuando entren a la página aparezca un mensaje con imagen que deberé cargar yo. Y luego al cerrar o apretar un botón me redireccione a otra pagina
Tengo este código, pero no se como incorporarle la imagen

```
<?php 
     echo "<script>
                alert('Mensaje');
                window.location= 'web/index.php'
    </script>";
?>
```

Comment: estás utilizando jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qué tal @Juan Antonio Gonzalez Rosas bienvenido, el mensaje de alerta con texto e imagen y que redireccione a otra página al dar clic en cerrar o en el botón con `Bootstrap` y `JavaScript`, tienes más posibilidades de darle estilos y ajustarlo a tus necesidades

```html
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Mostrar Ventana Modal de forma Automática</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
   <script>
      $(document).ready(function()
      {
         $("#mostrarmodal").modal("show");
      });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

   <div class="modal fade" id="mostrarmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
           <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='web/index.php'" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
              <h3>¡Mensaje de alerta!</h3>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-body">
              <h4>Texto de la ventana con imagen</h4>
              <img id="myImg" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/5X-XTISCh7w/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;max-width:300px">   
       </div>
           <div class="modal-footer">
          <a href="web/index.php" class="btn btn-danger">Cerrar</a>
           </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Amiga, es justo lo que necesitaba. Te agradezco mucho.

Comment: @Juan Antonio Gonzalez Rosas Si es la respuesta, marcarla como aceptada, que bueno que te ayudó